# Get object from array of objects depending on a specific property

Tags: javascript

Lets say we have the following:

```
let x = [
{"color": "blue", "cat": "eec" },
{"color": "red", "cat": "vbs" },
{"color": "black", "cat": "asd" },
]
```

how can I sort this by cat?
so that I can then do something like

```
let y = sorted.asd.color;

or 

y = sorted[asd][color];
```

note: cat is unique

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Hint - you'll use array.sort and localeCompare - look those up and if you get stuck in your attempt, come back to ask for help

Comment: the [array method `.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#syntax) can take a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group a Javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898272/group-a-javascript-array)

Comment: @asyncawait OP wants to convert the array to an object. "Sort" is not the correct term.

Comment: OP probably want to group by or something like this instead of sorting, but it's hard to understand  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @jabaa whats up my name is jared and i dont know how 2 read

Comment: @asyncawait I'd be very interested to see a solution using `sort`.

Comment: @jabaa `array.prototype.sort = array.prototype.reduce` ezpz 

Comment: @asyncawait Please post this as an answer. I'd like to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.reduce`:

```js
let x = [
{"color": "blue", "cat": "eec" },
{"color": "red", "cat": "vbs" },
{"color": "black", "cat": "asd" },
]

const sorted = x.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.cat] = el;
  return acc;
}, {});

const y = sorted.asd.color;

console.log(y);
```

or `.map` and `Object.entries`:

```js
let x = [
{"color": "blue", "cat": "eec" },
{"color": "red", "cat": "vbs" },
{"color": "black", "cat": "asd" },
]

const sorted = Object.fromEntries(x.map(el => [el.cat, el]));

const y = sorted.asd.color;

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```js
const x = [
    {"color": "blue", "cat": "eec" },
    {"color": "red", "cat": "vbs" },
    {"color": "black", "cat": "asd" },
]

function sortByCat(array) {
    let cats = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let currentObject = array[i];
        cats[currentObject.cat] = currentObject;
    }

    return cats;
}

let sorted = sortByCat(x);

let y = sorted.asd.color;
y = sorted['asd']['color'];
```